# fulltext index where contains uses column not text value or variable

Tags: sql, indexing, contains, full-text-search

I'm trying to run a query where I have a fulltext index on a column and I want to run a query with a contains statement where that column is looking for a match with a column in another table...not with a static text value or variable....is this even possible?

```
select a.field1, a.field2, c.x, c.y, c.z
from dbo.TableA a
cross apply(select x,y,z
            from dbo.TableB b
            where contains(b.x, a.field1)
```

c

Thank you!!!!

Comment: Are you getting any errors? I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

this way is impossible, but instead you can use this. In this scenario I create (|) delimited list using SELECT statement. The bar symbol (|) may be used instead of the OR keyword to represent the OR operator.

```
DECLARE @Searchwords nvarchar(4000) = N''
SELECT @Searchwords += '|' + a.field1
FROM dbo.TableA a
SELECT @Searchwords = STUFF(@Searchwords, 1, 1, '')

SELECT b.x, b.y, b.z
FROM dbo.TableB b
WHERE CONTAINS(b.x, @Searchwords)
```